# Passing Contents of File as Parameter to Sql*Plus Command

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to write a sqlplus command that creates a table from a query that is stored in an .sql file.

The particular .sql file that contains the query would be supplied to my sqlplus command as a variable (`&v_InputQuery`).

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE &v_OutputTable AS
(
< &v_InputQuery
)
;
```

I get an error saying that there's a missing SELECT keyword.

What I'd really like is for `&v_InputQuery` to be replaced not with the name of the file specified by the user, but with the actual contents of the file.  Is there a way to do that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does the file (name) have to be supplied directly to SQL*Plus, or can you use an intermediate shell script (or batch file if you're on Windows)?

Comment: @Alex Poole I'm new to the UNIX environment, so I'm not familiar with shell scripting.  I'm just setting this up as a convenience to myself, so that I don't have to constantly go into the underlying queries and wrap them with a CREATE TABLE...AS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, You cannot create a SQL*Plus command, but instead create a shell script to do it!

Lets say `my_script.sh` is below

```
#you can always complete the user interaction at unix/dos
USER=your_user
PASS=your_pass
DB=your_db
OUTPUT_TABLE=$1;
QUERY_FILE=$2;
SELECT_QUERY=`cat $QUERY_FILE`;

sqlplus -S ${USER}/${PASS}@${DB} << !
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
VAR EXITCODE NUMBER;

BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' CREATE TABLE $OUTPUT_TABLE AS $SELECT_QUERY ';
   :EXITCODE := SQLCODE;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
   :EXITCODE := SQLCODE;
END;
/

exit :EXITCODE
!
```

**Executing the script as below(Depends on OS)**

```
ksh my_script MY_OUTPUT_TABLE my_sql.sql;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I haven't had any experience with shell scripts, but I look forward to trying this out.

Comment: Why dynamic SQL? I'm not sure what that's adding as the statement is formed on the fly anyway.

Comment: @AlexPoole I just editted to add the user/password variables, and it runs perfectly fine, what ever posted above. There are N number of ways, either to print the DDL and run it manually, or straight away print the variable. what ever comes as $XX inside unix script will be treated as UNIX variable only!! because it uses `INTERPRETER`. `Execute Immediate`, makes some sense to read the script!

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar - I wasn't saying it wouldn't work, just querying what the `execute immediate` is adding over just having the `create` command on its own. Since the statement is fully formed by the time it's parsed either way, there is no dynamic element as far as SQL is concerned. I've added a separate answer to show what I mean - I think we could go around in circles in comments!

Comment: @AlexPoole No problems, I am  very very busy now with an iPad project, unable to spend on SO much.. you rock! After all every solution is good! Depends on the beholder.. Njoy :)

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar Thank you very much for pointing me in the general direction of a script.  I'm just getting my feet wet in Linux, and this is obviously something I need to know.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that. If your query is in a file called `v_InputQuery.sql`, you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE &v_OutputTable AS (
@v_InputQuery.sql
) ;
```

It's important that the `@` is the first character on the line. SQL*Plus will read the file and put its contents at that location. So make sure you don't have any terminating characters in the file such as `;` or `/`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll try this out as soon as I can. I think one of the challenges might be that I actually want the name of the file to be in the form of a variable that can take on different values depending on the user's input.

Comment: @Steve - you could replace `@v_InputQuery.sql` with a variable holding the file name, e.g. `@&v_InputQuery`; is that what you mean? (I don't think the parentheses are necessary or adding anything - though they don't hurt unless your query file already has a terminating `;` or `/`?)

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp - I was able to get your approach to work when I removed the terminal semicolon from the query in my .sql file.  Thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: Sorry @Steve, I thought that was obvious (since the contents of the file get inserted verbatim at that position) but will add that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding a comment, @MaheswaranRavisankar's approach will work, but the dynamic SQL (i.e. `execute immediate`) isn't necessary, so the anonymous block isn't necessary either. It can be simplified somewhat to:

```
USER=your_user
PASS=your_pass
DB=your_db
OUTPUT_TABLE=$1;
QUERY_FILE=$2;
SELECT_QUERY=`cat $QUERY_FILE`;

sqlplus -S ${USER}/${PASS}@${DB} << !
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
CREATE TABLE $OUTPUT_TABLE AS $SELECT_QUERY
!
```

This also allows you to use a query which is already terminated by a `;` or `/`, which the `execute immediate` version wouldn't like - you just need to decide whether your wrapper script needs one to match what your query files will contain.

Even the `whenever ...` line isn't vital, but the other answer tried to exit with the error code so I've mimicked that too somewhat. This will always exit with a generic failure status though (`1` in Unix, not sure what Windows does). You can then test if it was successful with `$?` in the script if you want to.

You can exit with the actual SQL error instead of the generic value, by using `whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode` instead. The problem with doing that is that most (all?) shells limit the return code to the range 0-255, so most errors will wrap and give something unhelpful anyway - a fairly-likely `ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object` error would give a shell exit value of 187, for example. And it's possible the wrapped value would be zero, which would mask that an error occurred at all; an also-plausible `ORA-01536: space quota exceeded for tablespace '%s'` error would give a shell exit code of zero, which is unhelpful. Using `exit failure` would at least stop that.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm new to shell scripting, so this took me much longer than it should have.  In the end, though, it worked perfectly.  Thank you very much for your answer, and for the detailed explanation.